# Photoshop CS4 - what does a small circled 'x' mean next to a cursor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac

In a new layer in a CS4 Photoshop document (Mac), my shape tool cursor has a small circle with an 'x' in it - to the bottom-right of the crosshair. What does this mean? If I try to draw a rectangle, the outline is created but it is not filled with the current foreground colour. Anyone know what might be causing this? I tried taking a screenshot but the screenshot utility doesn't capture the active cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh - I had 'paths' selected instead of 'fill pixels' in the tools options (Icons in top-left of screen on my version). Looks like the icon is there to remind you of this - except I had forgotten what it meant. Its been a while since I used P'shop...

Comment: so now whats your plan?? i think faraay lead you to this....

Comment: I posted my on solution 7 minutes before him.

Answer (score 2):

Does your cursor look like this?  [image: intersect cursor]

If so, it means your shape tool is set to "Intersect path areas".

[image: Path intersect tool options]